# Is it possible to deploy a service selectively to node?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am deploying a service with docker-swarm mode. So I have a manager and 4 nodes which means I have 5 instances total. 
but I want to split 2 and 2 worker nodes and deploy two different service to them without making another instance.

is it actually possible? 
Like 
instance 1(manager) - manager service a, b
instance 2(worker) - service a
instance 3(worker) - service a
instance 4(worker) - service b
instance 4(worker) - service b

because i don't want to get another instance to only have another manager.. but can't find any reasonable solution anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using node labels -

`--constraint 'node.labels.service== myservice1'`

In YAML -

```
  placement:
    constraints: [node.labels.service == myservice1 ]
```

You just need to make sure you are nodes in swarm mode are labelled correctly.

Labels update - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_update/

Ref -
 Single service - https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint

YAML - https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/admin/configure/add-labels-to-cluster-nodes/#deploy-a-service-with-constraints